# Duplicate stdout, pipe it to two different commands, collect results from both to stdin of final program

Tags: shell, unix, pipe

Say I have three programs: **generator**, that produces input data fed to **processor** and **verifier** that can check if processor output is correct for given input (so it needs both files).

What I currently do is:

```bash
generator > in.txt && processor < in.txt > out.txt && cat in.txt out.txt | verifier
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result without using explicit files? I've read about duplicating input using tee and and process substitution, but I didn't find a way to collect both streams into single one for final step.

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t want to create real files on your slow hard-disk, you can use FIFOs (First In First Out), which are also called *named pipes*, because of their behaviour.

```
mkfifo myfifo
generator | tee myfifo | processor | verifier myfifo
```

This streams the generated content to `tee`, which duplicates it to `myfifo` and to `stdout`, which is piped through the `processor` to the `verifier`. And the `verifier` also gets the stream from `myfifo`.

Answer (score 4):

I have not tested this, but try:

```
{ generator | tee /dev/stderr | processor ; } 2>&1  | verifier
```

This will redirect *a copy of* `generator` output to `stderr`. Then run `processor` on `stdout` of `generator`. Then combine both & pipe to `verifier`.

However, this cannot guarantee the order, in which lines from generator & processor would reach verifier.

---

Alternately, you can try process substitution like below:

```
( generator | tee >(processor) ) | verifier
```

Comment: Last one is beautiful.

Comment: Last one is beautiful, yet less portable. iirc it works in `bash`, but not POSIX. just as a head's up for those who attempt it on another shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the processor code to output sequentially `stdin` then `stdout` the one-line command could be simple as this:

```
generator | processor | verifier
```

Otherwise you can use this

```
generator | tee in.txt | processor | verifier in.txt
```

The tee command duplicate the `stdout` and redirect one stream to `in.txt` and the other towards the next pipe. In this case you have to modify `verifier` to read the output of `processor` from the `stdin` and the file generated by `generator` is passed as parameter.

I know you're searching a method to duplicate and redirect the `stdin` to `stdout` but i'm not aware of this and honestly I don't think it is possible

Comment: I think I tried this approach, and it didn't work because there is no guarantee that in.txt will be done writing by tee before verifier starts reading it (so it ended up reading empty file).

Comment: It's the duty of every process to verify the validity of the input parameters. Just return if input parameters are invalid.

Comment: @KimStrauss, if you want some synchronization between the `generator` and `processor` lines fed to `verifier`, you have to arrange for `processor` to do the interleaving. Else just do something along the lines given by the answer by DavideBerra: Stuff outputs somewhere, then call `verifier` on both.